# Displaying imageslider within a fragment

Tags: java, android

I have created an ImageSlider as a new activity seperate to my main project in order to see if it worked. Well guess what, it does! The problem is it is activity based, and when I try and implement it into my other project which has fragments I get so many errors within my MainActivity. Could someone help me please? I believe the issue might be related to my main project also having a navigation drawer & a fragment within the MainActivity main page of the app.

MainActivity test project code which works:

```
package com.example.user1.imageslidertest;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ViewPager viewPager;
    LinearLayout sliderDotspanel;
    private int dotscount;
    private ImageView[] dots;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.ViewPager);

        sliderDotspanel = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.SliderDots);

        ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(this);

        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        dotscount = viewPagerAdapter.getCount();
        dots = new ImageView[dotscount];

        for(int i = 0; i < dotscount; i++){

            dots[i] = new ImageView(this);
            dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.nonactive_dot));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            params.setMargins(8, 0, 8, 0);

            sliderDotspanel.addView(dots[i], params);

        }

        dots[0].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                for(int i = 0; i< dotscount; i++){
                    dots[i].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.nonactive_dot));
                }

                dots[position].setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.active_dot));

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter code:

```
package com.example.user1.imageslidertest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

private Context context;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Integer [] images = {R.drawable.a45large, R.drawable.a45largeintior, R.drawable.a45largerear};

public ViewPagerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    }

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return images.length;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_layout, null);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(images[position]);

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    vp.addView(view, 0);
    return view;

    }

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {

    ViewPager vp = (ViewPager) container;
    View view = (View) object;
    vp.removeView(view);

}
}
```

activity_main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.user1.imageslidertest.MainActivity">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/ViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/SliderDots"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/ViewPager"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingTop="300dp">
</LinearLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

custom_layout.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="292dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/a45large" />
</LinearLayout>
```

My MainActivity from my main project with fragments and navigation drawer (where the issues are when I put the test MainActivity code in):

```
package com.example.user1.mainproject;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
            implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
//      Code to display Home Fragment on App Launch Page
        HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        manager.beginTransaction().replace(
                R.id.relativelayout_for_fragment,
                homeFragment,
                homeFragment.getTag()
        ).commit();
    }
```

This is the biggest issue I've faced within my project so would really apreciate some help, thanks!

Comment: How do you have two `MainActivity` classes?

Comment: one is for my pactice project, one is for my main project where i cant get it to work with the fragments

Comment: what is the errors you are facing? add the error log, pls

Comment: To be honest everything is an error that comes back. If you were to implement the other main activity into the mainactivity of the main project what would you do? Thats the bit im stuck on. Thanks